# How to add SSL certificate to amazon s3 bucket?

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3

I have domain to host static files, which points to s3 bucket. The issue is that it uses http.

How can I add SSL certificate to this domain for free? All solutions, which I found are paid, like propositions from amazon and cloudflare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this, it does not appear that can be done.  If all you're using is S3 for hosting and Route53 for redirection to the S3 bucket, there is nothing in the DNS layer that accommodates either http or https or any other protocol in the application layer.

Unfortunately, it seems S3 only offers http access when using the http endpoint.  There is server side encryption, however you're then talking about adding in additional services.  There is also a way to do it with Cloudfront, however again, adding in additional services.